# Error installing Pyodide and not finding the module 'piplite'

Tags: pyodide

[image: Error Message]

The image reference is given, one can have a look, and please guide me if you can...

Also, can anyone please tell me why 'piplite' is not being installed on my  windows PC. It always throws an error saying that the module 'piplite' is not found, and if I found "Pyodide" one more related thing which also not being install, it is just throwing an error.

Comment: I understood that piplite is part of the [JupyterLite](https://jupyterlite.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) ecosystem, see [here](https://github.com/jupyterlite/jupyterlite/blob/e57d460d16786030e38e7bedd4d1c7601bcf6bee/packages/pyolite-kernel/py/piplite/README.md?plain=1#L4). If you are using JupyterLite's files served from a static site on the internet you don't need to install anything in your system to use piplite in it. Go to that [JupyterLite page](https://jupyterlite.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) & click to try it on the orange buttons in the upper left side.

Comment: Please [edit] to paste the text used in the image into your question so that it can be read on all devices, quoted, edited, and found through search. As it stands now, [your image makes it hard to answer your question or for people with related issues to find your question](//meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-errors-when-asking-a-question). See the [formatting documentation](/editing-help) for tips to make your text appear nicely without resorting to images.

Answer (score 1):

Pyodide is not meant to be installed with Pip - you should be including it via a script tag to the appropriate CDN link, as [indicated in the Pyodide docs](https://pyodide.org/en/stable/usage/quickstart.html).